# Load JSON file that is dependent on the page name

Tags: angularjs, json

I have several pages that contain tables, I want to make a table directive so that code is reusable and easy to manage and place into other tables.

I need a way to get a JSON file using angular's `$http` service that is specific to that page. I have been able to use that service for retrieving an absolute JSON location, but i dont know how to go about retrieving one that is dynamic to the page the table directive is located in.

Example: The page is called goals, the JSON file accessed would be `/app_data/goals.json` and it is then populated into a table that is a directive in an Angular app.

If the page was called location, the JSON file accessed would be `app_data/location.json`.

What method should I be looking at in Angular?

Comment: You want to know how to get the page name or what you want, your question is not clear.

Comment: I reworded the question to explain better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking the [get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) method for the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

A basic usage:

```
$http.get("path_to_your_json_file").then(onComplete, onError);
```

Comment: How would I go about using a _general_ get method who's location can be changed dynamically for what page it is on?

Comment: first get the name of the page with: location.pathname.substring(1) and save the result in a var, then use this var in concatenate in the url, something like this:
var pageName = location.pathname.substring(1)
$http.get("app_data/" + pageName + ".json").then(onComplete, onError);